# Determining Big O

Tags: asymptotics

```
    i<--2
    while (i<n)
      someWork (...)
      i <-- power (i,2)
    done
```

> Given that someWork(...) is an O(n) algorithm, what is the worst case
>   time complexity?

I've found this question answered on this site with the solution of O(n log n), however I don't quite understand why. I know that the power function has O(log n), but I don't understand why the overall Big O of the loop becomes O(n log n) instead of just O(n). Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: You should clarify your question by including all the code, what does `...` represent? is `someWork(...)` just a function call, or is it a declaration?

Comment: Sorry, I believe someWork(...) is just a function call. This was all the pseudocode that was included in the question given to me.

Comment: What have you tried?  What are your thoughts?  We want to clear up your confusions, not just solve your problem for you.  Have you tried computing how many times the loop will iterate?  how long each iteration will take?  Have you read our reference questions on the topic, e.g., http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/192/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23593/755?  This is covered there.  A problem dump like this is usually not considered a great fit for this site.

Comment: In fact, your question is answered by the second answer to this question: [How to come up with the runtime of algorithms?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/192/755), so I'm going to vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @D.W. The whole premise of stackexchange sites is that there is value in answering questions on a specific case-by-case basis. That thread is very generic - one might as well just refer to a book instead, which contains the same material.

Comment: @NickAlger, I think we could have an interesting discussion about that premise -- but this comment thread isn't the right place for that general discussion.  I encourage you to post on Meta if you have concerns; that's probably a better place for that discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a very crucial component of Big-Oh analysis. That question is: given some number `n` and some code `p` how does the **MAXIMUM** runtime of `p(n)` differ with respect to time per each `n` -- that is, what are the bounds of `p(n)` with respect to `n`. When code tracing, create a tally.

Here, we see that `i` is initialized to 2. Then the code enters into a while loop. Then, while `i<n` we perform some work `n` number of times, since we know that `someWork(...)` has a maximum time complexity of `n` -- that is, linear time. We add `n` to our tally.

The next line of code is `i` gets initialized to `i` being raised to the power of `2`. This variable, `i` directly impacts the runtime of the loop, since i with respect to `n` governs the condition upon entering and exiting the loop. We now know that we will perform the loop `log(n)` times.

Putting it all together, we know that since `someWork(...)` takes linear time (`n`) and that we will perform `someWork(...)` log(n) times, we can compute the tally for the big-oh analysis of the function as `n*log(n)`

Does this make more sense now?

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that $O$ and worst-cases were related; they are not. Cf. [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-relate-to-worst-and-best-case).

Answer (score 1):

The loop runs `O(log(n))` times since it runs until `i > n` and each iteration `i := i^2`.

Assuming `someWork()` takes `O(n)` the total run time will be `O(nlogn)` since you're performing a task that take `O(n)`, `O(logn)` times (loop).