# Time complexity - least upper bound

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I know that Big $O$ notation is used to describe the upper bound of running time of an algorithm, if we consider time complexity of that algorithm. However, I'm not sure why the following is **not** stated everytime anyone attempts to explain time complexity or Big $O$ - the fact we're looking for the least upper bound of the running time.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but $O(n!)$ is known to be the highest complexity - much worse than exponential. If I have an algorithm whose running time is $O(n)$, then it is also $O(n^2)$, $O(n^3)$, $O(2^n)$, and $O(n!)$, because they are all upper bounds of its running time (I know that, because it's $O(n)$).

So is it possible to find the least upper bound of the running time? If I read an algorithm has complexity $O(2^n)$, does it mean it has been proven this is the least upper bound? Or is it just the smallest upper bound that has been found **so far**?

Comment: In your second paragraph, $O(n!)$ is by far not the highest complexity. Take, for example, the function $n!^{n!}$. For the body of your question, have you looked at $\Theta(.)$ estimates (aka, big-Theta)? They apply here.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/23068/755

Comment: @D.W. check page 23 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=HJ9gds_zhVEC&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=big+o+notation+least+upper+bound&source=bl&ots=r_NrZw_0kP&sig=7LXybmWgwwJY8nlE9-2yU-FDAHA&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=big%20o%20notation%20least%20upper%20bound&f=false) to see what I mean (the last sentence on that page). Running time of an algorithm can be $O(n^2)$, but how do we know if it's not $O(n)$? If somebody tells me this algorithm is $O(n^2)$, does it mean he has proven there doesn't exist a smaller upper bound, for instance $O(n)$?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to state that $O(f(n))$ is the best bound on the complexity that you can get, then you can use big Theta instead: $\Theta(f(n))$ stands for a function – in this case worst-case time complexity – that is asymptotically equal to $f(n)$ up to constants. That is, if the worst-case time complexity $T(n)$ satisfies $cf(n) \leq T(n) \leq Cf(n)$ for some $0<c\leq C$, then you can state that the (worst-case) time complexity of the algorithm is $\Theta(f(n))$. This implies both the upper bound $O(f(n))$ and the matching lower bound $\Omega(f(n))$, showing that the upper bound is best possible.

Comment: If bubble sort has complexity $O(n)$, does it mean it has been proven this is **the least** upper bound possible (meaning no smaller upper bound exists)? Or is it the least upper bound that has been found so far?

Comment: Usually it implies that this is the least upper bound possible, though formally it's just an upper bound.