# Need confirmation for and answer related to algorithm notations(ϴ,O and Ω)

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

In my class we have to answer a question:

1. Having this pseudocode:

   `XPTO(n)
   sum = 0
   if even(n)
       for i=1 to n
           sum = sum + i
   else sum = 0`

and *knowing that even(n) have complexity ϴ(1)*, we can say the complexity of XPTO is ϴ(n)? Justify.

How do I justify this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the algorithm is O(_)"? Which cost model are working with? Why do you have O in the worst but Ω in the best case? See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-relate-to-worst-and-best-case).

Comment: thanks! I understood what you mean. I will answer in a better way.