# What is the time complexity of the piece of code given below

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

```
int IsPrime(n)
{
    int i, n;
    for (i=2; i<=sqrt(n);i++)
        if(n%i == 0)
            {printf("Not Prime \n"); return 0;}
    return 1;
}
```

Here the loop executes for $ \Theta (\sqrt{n}) $ time . But my teacher said that it is not  because the lower bound is $ \omega (1) $ I was not able to understand why it so .

Q1] Could some of you explain which one of us is right justifying reason ?

Q2] What is the importance of  " return 0 " ? What would have been the change if there had no " return 0 inside looping function ?

Q3] In general What is the meaning of return 0, 1, -1 in C programming language ? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604196/difference-between-return-1-return-0-and-return-1-and-exit) from stackoverflow but that didn't solve . Need little bit explanation

Comment: Regarding Q3: Questions about programming languages are off-topic here. You might want to read a tutorial or a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return). If you wouldn't have a return 0 in the loop the function wouldn't behave as its name implies it should. It'd return 1 for all numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The loop executes at most $O(\sqrt n)$ times because `i` is incremented in every iteration of the loop. You claim that it is also executed at least $\Omega(\sqrt n)$ times. This is not true because it has an early exit (the `return` statement). For example for even numbers the function returns during the first iteration.

If you recall the definition of $\Omega$, we have $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$ if there is some constant $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ we have $c*g(n) < f(n)$ for some constant $c$. By this definition the runtime of your program can't be $\Omega(\sqrt n)$ because the loop makes only one iteration for infinitely many inputs (that is, you can't find a suitable $n_0$).

You can of course restrict your analysis to the worst case ($n$ is a prime number). Then you are correct in saying that the runtime is $\Theta(\sqrt n)$. There is a question about [the relation of $O$, $\Omega$, best and worst case](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-%CE%A9-relate-to-worst-and-best-case) in case you find this confusing.

Comment: $ \omega ( \sqrt{n} )$ is also possible right ?  According to Cormen we take that function which is asymptotically closest . dont we ? Which made me think it is $\theta(\sqrt{n})$ What is wrong about my assumption  ?

Comment: Given function is definitely $\mathcal{0}(n)$ 
ie For some class of input the given function is $\Omega(1)$ and for some class of input the given function is $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ And the function is asymptotically closest to $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$   Hence it is $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$

Comment: @AkhilNadhPC,  The answer already explains what is wrong with that.  I suggest you re-read it.  See especially the sentence that starts "This is not true because..."  "Asymptotically closest" is not the definition of $\omega$ nor $\Theta$.  I suggest you look up their mathematical definition and take another look at it; they are precise mathematical terms with a specific definition, and in case of doubt, looking at the definition is the way to definitively resolve your doubt.

Comment: Got it i missed for all n0 > n

Comment: For all even n, the loop iterates once and only once (except for n = 0 or n = 2, where it doesn't iterate at all).

Comment: What is the importance of " return 0 " . What would have been the change if there is no return 0  inside the loop?