# What is the difference between Big-O and worst-case run time?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Big-O describes an upper bound on run time. Is that not the definition of "worst-case"?

For example, how can we say that a hash table insertion require O(1) time on average? Constant time is the best case, *n* time is the worst case. How can an upper bound describe an average run time? In what sense is that bound "upper"?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: It's multiple ways of asking the same question for clarity. If you can't follow the plot then you can't follow the plot.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) says:

> Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity.

So it is not the definition of the "worst case".

[Wikipedia defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case#Worst-case_-case_versus_average-case_performance) best, **worst**, and average cases as

> In computer science, best, worst, and average cases of a given algorithm express what the resource usage is at least, **at most** and on average, respectively.

By resource we usually refer to time or/and space (memory) required to solve a certain problem.

[It also says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms):

> Big O notation is a convenient way to express the worst-case scenario for a given algorithm, although it can also be used to express the average-case - for example, the worst-case scenario for quicksort is $O(n^2)$, but the average-case run-time is $O(n\log{n})$.

To sum up: Big-O notation is a pure mathematical concept and notation, which is used in Computer science to express the worst-case scenario for a given algorithm.

Here we have some useful posts:

- [How does one know which notation of time complexity analysis to use?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-does-one-know-which-notation-of-time-complexity-analysis-to-use)
- [How do O and Ω relate to worst and best case?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-%CE%A9-relate-to-worst-and-best-case)
- [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth)

Comment: > [Definition of Big O] is not the definition of the "worst case".

> Big-O notation ... is used in Computer science to express the worst-case scenario for a given algorithm.

Comment: @CowPowPow  You should differentiate "to express" and "definition of". For example, we express the velocity $v(t)$ as the integral 
$\int a(t)dt$ of the acceleration, but it does not make the integral to be the definition of the velocity, does it? Integral exists independently from the velocity as Big-O exists independently from the worst/average case analysis.

Comment: Yeah actually that is a definition. That's exactly what the word "definition" means in english.