# Time Complexity of the code

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, binary-trees, recursion

I am having trouble finding the time complexity of the below code.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution(object):
    def isBalanced(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """

        if root is None:
            return True

        def height(root):
            if root is None:
                return 0
            left = height(root.left)
            right = height(root.right)

            return 1 + max(left, right)


        def check(root):
            if root is None:
                return True


            if abs(height(root.left) - height(root.right)) < 2:
                return(check(root.left) and check(root.right))
            else:
                return False


        return check(root)
```

Is it `O(n^2)` or `O(n)` because first we are checking for the root, and that takes `O(n)` time and then we check for the left subtree and the right subtree, where the elements searched are halved each time?

Thanks!

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, pseudo code and arguments of correctness. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related meta discussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has worst-case complexity $\Omega(n^{1.5})$. Consider a tree of height $h$ which is composed of a "backbone" of $h$ nodes, out of the $i$th of which (counting from the root) there is a path to the right ending at depth $h$. As an example, here is the case $h=4$:
[image]

The height is computed along the entire backbone. The subtree rooted at the backbone node of depth $h-\ell+1$ has $\binom{\ell+1}{2}$ nodes (where $\ell=1$ corresponds to the backbone's leaf), and so computing the height of all subtrees along the backbone takes time proportional to
$$
\sum_{\ell=1}^h \binom{\ell+1}{2} = \binom{h+2}{3} = \Theta(h^3).
$$
In contrast, the tree contains $\binom{h+1}{2} = \Theta(h^2)$ nodes, so the running time in this case is $\Omega(n^{1.5})$ (in fact, it is $\Theta(n^{1.5})$ in this particular case).

Comment: why are you saying $Ω(n^{1.5})$ is the WORST case? doesn't $Ω$ mean that the time complexity is at least $Ω(n^{1.5})$ ? because I'm pretty sure bigO means worst case(less than or equal) and $Ω$ means best case (more than or equal)

Comment: @JohnP Here is a primer on these matters: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23068/how-do-o-and-%ce%a9-relate-to-worst-and-best-case.

Comment: I am not claiming that my example is the worst case. It does show, however, that the worst case complexity is at least $\Omega(n^{1.5})$.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have left and right graph each with n nodes.
Define complexity of check as $C(n)$ and complexity of height as $H(n)$.
Complexity of height calculation $H(2n) = 2H(n)$ is linear or
$H(n)\approx O(n)$.

Now complexity of check

$C(2n)=2C(n)+2H(n)=2\big(2C(n/2)+2H(n/2)\big)+2H(n)=$

$=4C(n/2)+4H(n/2)+4H(n/2)=4C(n/2)+8H(n/2)=$

$=...=2nC(1)+(2n\log_2 2n)H(1)$

So overall complexity is $O(n\log n)$.

It is unexpectedly good. At first I thought it will be worse than $O(n^2)$.

The algorithm can be improved to $O(n)$ if you combine height and check functions and return height and check together:

```
def height_and_check(root):
# returns height and check pair
    if root is None:
        return 0, True

    left_height, left_check = height_and_check(root.left)
    right_height, right_check = height_and_check(root.right)

    height = 1 + max(left_height, right_height)

    check = abs(left_height - right_height) < 2 \
            and left_check \
            and right_check

    return height, check
```

Comment: You're tacitly assuming that the tree is balanced. This only holds in the "Yes" cases.

Comment: Thank you for the new approach Ivan! If the tree is balanced, the complexity will be O(nlogn) or is it for the worst case?

Comment: O(nlogn) is the complexity of the algorithm in the question in the worst case where n is the number of nodes.